# Desktop switching in vista

Tags: c#

i have bulid an application in c# fro vista it loades in "winlogon" desktop when i logged on i want this application should switch to "deafult" deasktop. how can i do this in c#
Regards
Ehtsham

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this personally, but I imagine you would need to connect the app's main thread to the default desktop. Use the `SetThreadDesktop` API call to achieve this.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686744(VS.85).aspx) for some useful information.